# Metpy and dewpoint_rh

Tags: metpy

I just started getting the following error while running a program with Metpy:

importerror: cannot import name 'dewpoint_rh' from 'metpy.calc'

Yesterday my program was working fine.

Here is the snippet of code:

**from metpy.calc import (bunkers_storm_motion, bulk_shear, dewpoint, dewpoint_rh, dry_lapse, moist_lapse,
vapor_pressure, saturation_vapor_pressure, wind_speed, wind_direction, pressure_to_height_std,
mixing_ratio, cape_cin, wind_components, height_to_pressure_std, equivalent_potential_temperature,
parcel_profile, precipitable_water, storm_relative_helicity, mean_pressure_weighted,
most_unstable_cape_cin, most_unstable_parcel, supercell_composite, significant_tornado, get_layer,
relative_humidity_from_dewpoint)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dewpoint_rh` was the function name for calculating dewpoint from temperature and relative humidity in MetPy versions prior to 0.12. [This changed to `dewpoint_from_relative_humidity` in v0.12, and the old name was removed in v1.0](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/pull/1208).

For additional information on the API changes in MetPy v1.0 (which are likely to impact the use of the functions you are importing), please see [the MetPy 1.0 API Changes guide](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/userguide/apichange.html) in MetPy's documentation.